# How to use outer join in below example?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I am creating 2 queries:

1

```
select count(c.id) as cid1, p.name as pname1, u.name as uname1 
from crm_lead c, account_period p, res_users u 
where c.create_date between p.date_start and p.date_stop and 
      (c.user_id = u.id or c.sales_vertical=u.id) and 
      u.id = 1 
group by p.name, u.name
```

2

```
select count(c.id) as cid2, p.name as pname2, u.name as uname2 
from crm_lead c, account_period p, res_users u 
where c.create_date between p.date_start and p.date_stop and
      (c.user_id = u.id or c.sales_vertical=u.id) and 
      stage_id =12 and 
      u.id = 1 
where a.pname = b.pname 
group by p.name, u.name
```

I am getting the following resuls for the above 2 queries

result for q1 :

```
 cid1         pname1      uname1                                       
 11           07/2011     admin                                        
 5            08/2011     admin                                        
 9            09/2011     admin
```

result for q2 :

```
 cid2        pname2    uname2                                          
 9           07/2011   admin                                           
 3           09/2011   admin
```

after combining both the queries I am getting following output:

```
 cid1  cid2  pname1    pname2     uname1     uname2                    
 11     9     07/2011   07/2011   admin      admin                     
 9      3     09/2011   09/2011   admin      admin
```

But I want the result as

```
 cid1   cid2  pname1    pname2    uname1     uname2                    
 11     9     07/2011   07/2011   admin      admin                     
 5      0     08/2011   08/2011   admin      admin                     
 9      3     09/2011   09/2011   admin      admin
```

How can it be done?

My combined query is below:

```
select a.cid1, b.cid2, a.pname1, b.pname2, a.uname1, b.uname2 
from (select count(c.id) as cid1, p.name as pname1, u.name1 as uname 
      from crm_lead c, account_period p, res_users u 
      where c.create_date between p.date_start and p.date_stop and 
            (c.user_id = u.id or c.sales_vertical=u.id) and 
            u.id = 1 
      group by p.name, u.name) as a,
     (select count(c.id) as cid2, p.name as pname2, u.name as uname2 
      from crm_lead c, account_period p, res_users u 
      where c.create_date between p.date_start and p.date_stop and
            (c.user_id = u.id or c.sales_vertical=u.id) and 
            stage_id =12 and 
            u.id = 1 
      group by p.name, u.name)as b 
where a.pname1 = b.pname2
```

Comment: 1. In your second query there's an error: `where a.pname = b.pname` must be `and a.pname = b.pname`
2. Please format the question with code taggings. This is not readable.
3. Please provide your table structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your requested result the query could look like this:

```
SELECT a.cid1
      ,COALESCE(b.cid2, 0) AS cid2
      ,a.pname1
      ,COALESCE(b.pname2, a.pname2) AS pname2
      ,a.uname1
      ,COALESCE(b.uname2, a.uname2) AS uname2
FROM  (<query1>)  a
LEFT   JOIN (<query2>) b ON a.pname1 = b.pname2
```

I have my doubts, however, that you actually want that exact result.

Comment: Also, How can I use outer join for 2 or more subqueries?

Answer (score 1):

Try using LEFT JOIN:

```
    select a.cid1, b.cid2, a.pname1, b.pname2, a.uname1, b.uname2 from

    (select count(c.id) as cid1, p.name as pname1, u.name1 as uname from crm_lead c, account_period p, res_users u where c.create_date between p.date_start and p.date_stop and (c.user_id = u.id or c.sales_vertical=u.id) and u.id = 108 group by p.name, u.name) as a

left join

    (select count(c.id) as cid2, p.name as pname2, u.name as uname2 from crm_lead c, account_period p, res_users u where c.create_date between p.date_start and p.date_stop and(c.user_id = u.id or c.sales_vertical=u.id) and stage_id =12 and u.id = 108 group by p.name, u.name) as b on a.pname1 = b.pname2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ANSI-92 explicit join syntax, rather than the older implicit join syntax:

```
select a.cid1, 
       coalesce(b.cid2,0) cid2, 
       a.pname1, 
       coalesce(b.pname2, a.pname1) pname2, 
       a.uname1, 
       coalesce(b.uname2, a.uname1) uname2
from (select count(c.id) as cid1, p.name as pname1, u.name1 as uname 
      from crm_lead c
      join account_period p on (c.create_date between p.date_start and p.date_stop)
      join res_users u on (c.user_id = u.id or c.sales_vertical=u.id) and u.id=108 
      group by p.name, u.name) as a
left join
     (select count(c.id) as cid2, p.name as pname2, u.name as uname2 
      from crm_lead c
      join account_period p on c.create_date between p.date_start and p.date_stop
      join res_users u 
        on (c.user_id = u.id or c.sales_vertical=u.id) and stage_id=12 and u.id=108 
      group by p.name, u.name) as b 
  on a.pname1 = b.pname2
```